# How to endlessly loop a GridView in Android?

Tags: java, android, gridview, sdk

I want a GridView in Android to loop endlessly / repeat all items when the GridView is scrolled.

For example let's say the GridView has 1 column and 3 items.
I want it to be displayed like that:
...
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 1
....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your adapter return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` for `getCount()` and then for getView grab your data by using `myData[position % myData.length]`

Comment: then how to get the original position of the item in the List<>